# Why is the code not running? There is a issue with the json file

Tags: python, discord.py

I am building a discord bot but it just won't run. I tried everything. Help me! I am building an economy discord bot. I think there is some issue with the lists in the json file. When I run, it says command "" not found. I have tried literally everything. Help me as soon as possible @Python!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
os.chdir("FOLDER PATH PROVIDED")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("In Development"))
    print("Ready")


@client.command
async def balance(ctx):
    await users(ctx.author)
    users = await data()

    user = ctx.author

    wallet_amount = users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"]
    bank_amount = users[str(user.id)]["Bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title="Account")
    em.add_field(name="Wallet", value=wallet_amount)
    em.add_field(name="Bank", value=bank_amount)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)


@client.command
async def beg(ctx):
    await account(ctx.author)
    users = await data()
    user = ctx.author
    earning = random.randrange(101)
    await ctx.send(f"Someone gave you {earning}")
    users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = + earning

    with open("bank.json") as file:
        json.dump(users, file)


async def account(user):
    data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False

    else:
        users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] = 0

    with open("bank.json") as file:
        json.dump(users, file)
        return True


async def data():
    with open("bank.json") as file:
        accounts = json.load(file)
    return accounts


client.run("TOKEN PROVIDED")
```

The json file:

```
{

}
```

Comment: "it just won't run...When I run"???

Comment: "Help me as soon as possible": that's inappropriate on SO. People here are volunteering their expertise to help others. You don't get to ask for anything ASAP unless you're the boss or the client paying the bill.

Comment: This is too much bruhh

Answer (score 0):

you are miss interpreting event and command,

> @client.command() is correct..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).